# Get page URL by using a program within a pageviewerwebpart in SharePoint

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, web-parts, hitcounter

I have a simple hit counter written in c# .net. I placed that counter to many pages using the pageviewerwebpart. What I want to do is, not only counting the hits, but also which page triggered the hit counter. So how can I retrieve the page URL with my hit counter ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Request.ServerVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx).

You are probably after `Request.ServerVariables["URL"]`.

Comment: This just gives the URL of the program but I need to know web URL that contains my program, so that I can learn which page of my website triggered "/MyProgram/Default.aspx"

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are after. Are you looking for the HTTP_REFERER server variable?

Answer (score 0):

The get the url of the page that linked to the current page use:

```
var referrer = Request.Urlreferrer;
```

if your app is in say an IFRAME you can check it using

```
parent.location.href;
```

this works only when running on the same domain / site url though, because of cross scripting security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]`. After bit of research I got the url from `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]`.

Regards,
Ajay Raghuwanshi

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem I have had with the urls. You can use `Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()` in a page_load sub, but it only works when the page is first loaded.  If you do a refresh then it gets the url of the page contained in the pageviewerwebpart instead.  I implemented a workaround using cookies. Here is my post over at Sharepoint Stack Exchange: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33617/how-to-get-the-url-name-of-a-subsite-from-a-webpart

Ah, I also found another solution using query parameters, which I mention in my own answer.